# Create timeseries by grouping using date and hour

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
  START_DATE    END_DATE  START_HOUR  END_HOUR  CURTAILED_OTC_MW
0  04-11-2015  31-10-2016         1.0      18.0             700.0
1  04-11-2015  31-10-2016         1.0      18.0             700.0
2  30-01-2016  30-01-2016         5.0      14.0             708.0
3  30-01-2016  30-01-2016        15.0      18.0             658.0
4  04-11-2015  31-03-2016         1.0      24.0            1368.0
5  04-11-2015  31-03-2016         1.0      24.0            1368.0
```

I am trying to group the dataframe based on four columns and want the output to look something like this

```
START_DATE    END_DATE  START_HOUR  END_HOUR  CURTAILED_OTC_MW
0  04-11-2015  31-10-2016         1.0      18.0            1400.0
1  30-01-2016  30-01-2016         5.0      14.0            1364.0
2  04-11-2015  31-03-2016         1.0      24.0            2736.0
```

When I try to use `groupby`,it gives me the following output

```
g = data.groupby(['START_DATE','END_DATE','START_HOUR','END_HOUR']).sum()

                                       CURTAILED_OTC_MW
START_DATE END_DATE   START_HOUR END_HOUR                  
01-01-2002 31-01-2020 1.0        24.0              200187.0
01-01-2011 31-01-2020 1.0        19.0               91000.0
                                 24.0              182000.0
01-01-2016 01-01-2016 6.0        14.0                9937.0
                                 16.0               19874.0
```

How do I create a timeseries based on this for every day in2016 which would have every hour in 2016 followed by MW value for that hour?

For example, for 01/01/2016

```
Date                  
01-01-2016 00:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 01:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 02:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 03:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 04:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 05:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 06:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 07:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 08:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 09:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 10:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 11:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 12:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 13:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 14:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 15:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 16:00           402061.0
01-01-2016 17:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 18:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 19:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 20:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 21:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 22:00           382187.0
01-01-2016 23:00           382187.0
```

Comment: Can you please include an example of your code

Comment: Please edit the question to be not duplicate